# Google Sheets: Create a Dropdown menu maintaining font formatting within the source range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu, formatting

I have a Google Sheet with a list of formatted text that is generated based on user input.

[image]

I now want to create a dropdown menu based on this list with the color formats still intact as it is added information for the user.

Is this possible? If not, what other workaround is there?

Will greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: I don't think that is possible but I hope I will be proven wrong.

Comment: I did try to do something very close to what you are trying. It may not be the answer you are searching but it will be similar to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, there is no way to format the dropdown choices. Aside from that, this should copy the style of the `inRange` cells to the `outRange` cells.

```
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var inRange = sheets.getRange('A2:A4');
var outRange = sheets.getRange('C2:C10');

function createDropDown(){
  var rangeRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(inRange).build();
  outRange.setDataValidation(rangeRule); // set dropdown to your range
}

function onEdit() {
  var inValues = inRange.getValues().flat();
  var outValues = outRange.getValues().flat();
  var inStyles = inRange.getRichTextValues().flat();
  var outStyles = [];

  outValues.forEach(function(outValue){
    var match = inValues.indexOf(outValue);
    outStyles.push([inStyles[match]]);
  });

  outRange.setRichTextValues(outStyles);
}
```

Sample:

[image: sample output]

Comment: Hi NaziA, thanks for your feedback, much appreciated. Problem is, I need to find a way to notify the user of the different color codes as they indicate pickup and drop off points which is needed for selection. For the time being, I am planning to indicate them using different brackets for pickup and drop off points, but preference would be the color codes indicated. Is there a way to make an exact copy of such a cell? I.e. copy a cell with multiple font colors within it to another cell with the same font colors? I was looking at getTextStyle(startOffset, endOffset) but failing to implement.

Comment: Thanks to you @Shalin, I was able to see something similar. I'm using `getRichTextValues` and `setRichTextValues` instead. I have updated my answer. Same with the issue with dropdown, we can't format it. But for the cell, we can copy the exact style from the range we are checking. Also, if you edit that range, it will update the style of the cells that have that text.